# How to create a new row based on all cells in an existing R dataframe

Tags: r, calculated-columns

I want to creat a new row based on all other cells in an existing R dataframe.
Here is the existing R dataframe called "dat1".

```
dat1 <- structure(list(a = c(0.80, -0.72, 1.36, 1.57, -0.58), 
                       b = c(-1.39, 0.66, -0.01, 1.24, 1.19), 
                       c = c(0.35, 0.44, 0.32, 1.90, -0.11), 
                       d = c(-0.09, -1.26, 1.14, -0.37, 0.95), 
                       e = c(0.59, 0.05,-1.08, 1.44, 0.58), 
                       weight = c(3.2, 4.3, 5.6, 3.4, 5.2)), 
                   row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

"data" contains five rows and five columns. I want to create the sixth row.

```
data[6,1] = data[1,1]*data[1,6]+data[2,1]*data[2,6]+data[3,1]*data[3,6]+data[4,1]*data[4,6]+data[5,1]*data[5,6]
data[6,2] = data[1,2]*data[1,6]+data[2,2]*data[2,6]+data[3,2]*data[3,6]+data[4,2]*data[4,6]+data[5,2]*data[5,6]
data[6,3] = data[1,3]*data[1,6]+data[2,3]*data[2,6]+data[3,3]*data[3,6]+data[4,3]*data[4,6]+data[5,3]*data[5,6]
data[6,4] = data[1,4]*data[1,6]+data[2,4]*data[2,6]+data[3,4]*data[3,6]+data[4,4]*data[4,6]+data[5,4]*data[5,6]
data[6,5] = data[1,5]*data[1,6]+data[2,5]*data[2,6]+data[3,5]*data[3,6]+data[4,5]*data[4,6]+data[5,5]*data[5,6]code here
data[6,6] = NA
```

Here is what I tried:

Method 1

```
data[6,1] <- data[1,1]*data[1,6]+data[2,1]*data[2,6]+data[3,1]*data[3,6]+data[4,1]*data[4,6]+data[5,1]*data[5,6]
data[6,2] <- data[1,2]*data[1,6]+data[2,2]*data[2,6]+data[3,2]*data[3,6]+data[4,2]*data[4,6]+data[5,2]*data[5,6]
data[6,3] <- data[1,3]*data[1,6]+data[2,3]*data[2,6]+data[3,3]*data[3,6]+data[4,3]*data[4,6]+data[5,3]*data[5,6]
data[6,4] <- data[1,4]*data[1,6]+data[2,4]*data[2,6]+data[3,4]*data[3,6]+data[4,4]*data[4,6]+data[5,4]*data[5,6]
data[6,5] <- data[1,5]*data[1,6]+data[2,5]*data[2,6]+data[3,5]*data[3,6]+data[4,5]*data[4,6]+data[5,5]*data[5,6]
data[6,6] <- NA
```

I also tried to Method 2:

```
data1 <- data[1:5,1:5]
```

Then create a new dataframe called data2:

```
for (i in 1:5) {
  for (j in 1:5) {
    data2[i, j] <- data1[i, j] * data[j, 6]
  }
}
```

Then create a new row

```
newrow <- colSums(data2)
```

Then the final data3

```
data3 <- rbind(data1,newrow)
```

I found the results were different frome method 1 and 2.
Since my true dataset is much larger than the "data". I hope someone could help me with a easy way to calculte the new row.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you want `rbind(dat1, c(colSums(dat1[, 1:5] * dat1$weight), NA))`, but you should double check the results for one or two entries. This is a good post, but it is also helpful if you provide your desired output for the toy data set.

Answer (score 0):

The reason, why you get different results is, that you mixed up the indices in your `for`-loop. You want to calculated the weighted sum for each column. Thus you should loop over the columns and then multiply each column with the corresponding weight. In your `for`-loop you specify the weights wrong. You multiply the column `j` always with the weight of row `j`. Here is how you can fix this (in a fully reproducible way):

First the results for **Method 1**:

```
method1 <- dat1

method1[6,1] <- method1[1,1]*method1[1,6]+method1[2,1]*method1[2,6]+method1[3,1]*method1[3,6]+method1[4,1]*method1[4,6]+method1[5,1]*method1[5,6]
method1[6,2] <- method1[1,2]*method1[1,6]+method1[2,2]*method1[2,6]+method1[3,2]*method1[3,6]+method1[4,2]*method1[4,6]+method1[5,2]*method1[5,6]
method1[6,3] <- method1[1,3]*method1[1,6]+method1[2,3]*method1[2,6]+method1[3,3]*method1[3,6]+method1[4,3]*method1[4,6]+method1[5,3]*method1[5,6]
method1[6,4] <- method1[1,4]*method1[1,6]+method1[2,4]*method1[2,6]+method1[3,4]*method1[3,6]+method1[4,4]*method1[4,6]+method1[5,4]*method1[5,6]
method1[6,5] <- method1[1,5]*method1[1,6]+method1[2,5]*method1[2,6]+method1[3,5]*method1[3,6]+method1[4,5]*method1[4,6]+method1[5,5]*method1[5,6]
method1[6,6] <- NA

method1
#        a      b      c     d      e weight
# 1  0.800 -1.390  0.350 -0.09  0.590    3.2
# 2 -0.720  0.660  0.440 -1.26  0.050    4.3
# 3  1.360 -0.010  0.320  1.14 -1.080    5.6
# 4  1.570  1.240  1.900 -0.37  1.440    3.4
# 5 -0.580  1.190 -0.110  0.95  0.580    5.2
# 6  9.402  8.738 10.692  4.36  3.967     NA
```

Here is the modified **Method 2**:

```
data1 <- dat1[1:5, 1:5]
data2 <- data.frame(matrix(numeric(5*5), ncol = 5))
names(data2) <- letters[1:5]

for (i in 1:5) {
  for (j in 1:5) {
    data2[j, i] <- data1[j, i] * dat1[j, 6]
  }
}

method2 <- rbind(data1, colSums(data2))

method2 
#        a      b      c     d      e
# 1  0.800 -1.390  0.350 -0.09  0.590
# 2 -0.720  0.660  0.440 -1.26  0.050
# 3  1.360 -0.010  0.320  1.14 -1.080
# 4  1.570  1.240  1.900 -0.37  1.440
# 5 -0.580  1.190 -0.110  0.95  0.580
# 6  9.402  8.738 10.692  4.36  3.967
```

Ok, so now the results agree. I propose another way, **Method 3**:

```
dat1[6, ] <- c(apply(dat1[, 1:5], MARGIN = 2, function(x) sum(x * dat1[, 6])), NA)

dat1
#        a      b      c     d      e weight
# 1  0.800 -1.390  0.350 -0.09  0.590    3.2
# 2 -0.720  0.660  0.440 -1.26  0.050    4.3
# 3  1.360 -0.010  0.320  1.14 -1.080    5.6
# 4  1.570  1.240  1.900 -0.37  1.440    3.4
# 5 -0.580  1.190 -0.110  0.95  0.580    5.2
# 6  9.402  8.738 10.692  4.36  3.967     NA
```

How does this work? `apply` applies the function specfied to all columns (`MARGIN = 2`) of the data `dat1[, 1:5]`. The function calculates the product of the specific column (`x`) and the weights stored in `dat1[, 6]` and sums up the numbers. In the end we need to add the `NA` as there are six columns in `dat1` and `apply` only returns a vector of five values.

**Data**

```
dat1 <- structure(list(a = c(0.80, -0.72, 1.36, 1.57, -0.58), 
                       b = c(-1.39, 0.66, -0.01, 1.24, 1.19), 
                       c = c(0.35, 0.44, 0.32, 1.90, -0.11), 
                       d = c(-0.09, -1.26, 1.14, -0.37, 0.95), 
                       e = c(0.59, 0.05,-1.08, 1.44, 0.58), 
                       weight = c(3.2, 4.3, 5.6, 3.4, 5.2)), 
                  row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi kath, thanks so much for your helpful guidance! I learned a lot here!